# @@ROWCOUNT returns 0 on the first time

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I want to know how many rows I get with this query :

```
Using ConLoad As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(constring)
     Dim Query As String = "SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS ROWnum, *  FROM Specifications")

     ConLoad.Open()
     Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(Query, ConLoad)
         Response.Write(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
     End Using
End Using
```

This query executed in SQL Server Management Studio returns 38, but in my webform it's returning 0.

I improve to launch it twice:

```
Using ConLoad As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(constring)
    Dim Query As String = "SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS ROWnum, *  FROM Specifications")

    ConLoad.Open()
    Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(Query, ConLoad)
        Response.Write(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
    End Using
    Using cmd2 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(Query, ConLoad)
        Response.Write(cmd2.ExecuteScalar)
    End Using
End Using
```

And the result on `cmd2.ExecuteScalar` is 38.

How I have to do to have the good result at the first time?

Comment: Selecting all records of a table just to count its elements is very inefficient, use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable`, instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@@ROWCOUNT` is populated as the result of a query, not used within a query, you could use `COUNT(*)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Specifications
```

Or:

```
SELECT *
FROM Specifications
PRINT @@ROWCOUNT
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx):

> @@ROWCOUNT Returns the number of rows affected by the *last* statement ..

Generally [`COUNT(*)`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) is used to determine the number of results, where the result-set is not itself desired.